# Use Google API key safely in itch.io project

Tags: javascript, google-api, youtube-data-api, api-key

I created a HTML5 app that is using the YouTube Data API v3 and want to put it on itch.io

When I do this, the API key will be in some form in there, so people could find it (yes I could try to obfuscate, but that only makes it harder to find the key, not impossible).

So I want to restrict the project / API key as much as I can to prevent someone from misusing the key.

I hoped that I could somehow restrict it to only allow reading access (because that's all the app needs, it just queries view + like count and comments from videos), so nobody can use it to write a comment in my name or something like that. But I couldn't find that option.

What I could do so far is

1. I restricted the key to only use the YouTube Data API v3
2. I restricted the use to HTTP referrers and to the website https://v6p9d9t4.ssl.hwcdn.net/

That last domain is the place where itch.io puts the app. But if someone would take my key and put their app on itch.io as well, that would be the same domain, so it doesn't help, really.

Is there another option to make this more secure, that I haven't found? The only thing I can imagine now is, to write a service or FaaS that my app calls (without any key) and that then calls the API. But I would like to avoid that.

Comment: You could try using OAuth 2.0 implicit flow - https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/guides/authorization/client-side-web-apps.

Comment: Thanks, if I get this right, the user of my app would have to be logged into Google/YouTube already? That wouldn't work for me, I'm reading only public data and I don't want them to be forced to have a Google account / to log in.

Comment: Yes. If you don't want users to need a google account then I think the only solution is what you said: making your own api that your app uses.